# window.print() on IE8 resetting radio buttons

Tags: html, printing, internet-explorer-8

In my `ASP.Net MVC` project, I have used `window.print()` to allow user printing the current page. However, when I tested it on `Windows XP` and `IE 8` combination, I found that the actual print is showing all radio buttons reset to original default selection.

e.g. If there is a group of 3 radio buttons say "Monthly", "Quarterly" and "Yearly" with "Monthly" selected by default, then even if I select "Yearly" before printing the page, the actual printout shows "Monthly" as selected. But on a web page this selection remains as "Yearly".

I also tested it using `IE 9` with mode set as 'IE 8' where it is not reproduced.
What could be the reason of this internal resetting of radio buttons on printout? Is this related to browser compatibility?

Here is my HTML for one such group of buttons in my page:

```
<div>
     <input type="radio" id="freq-month" name="repayments" checked="checked" value="Monthly" />
     <label for="freq-month">Monthly</label>

     <input type="radio" id="freq-fortnight" name="repayments" value="Fortnightly" />            
     <label for="freq-fortnight">Fortnightly</label>

     <input type="radio" id="freq-week" name="repayments" value="Weekly" />
     <label for="freq-week">Weekly</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in IE<9.

One workaround is to print images instead of radio buttons. Use two different images for checked and unchecked buttons and set them to only be visible when printing by declaring @media print { }. Then switch them around whenever the user selects a different value.